# Allow users to open any music file on thier local storage with my vb.net music software

Tags: vb.net, mp3, onload

The issue on ground is the fact that, judging from a standard music player, as a user, I can just move to my desktop and pick a particular music file,then I right click and i open it with the standard music app and automatically it gets the song and play it.

So I want my desktop app made with visual studio,vb.net to have that same ability. I need the onload event code to carry out that functionality. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: We're not here to teach you from scratch or write your code for you. It's up to you to do the research to learn how to do what you want to do and do it. If what you do doesn't work, THEN you have an issue that you can ask about here. The fact that you have no badges indicates that you declined to take the site tour when prompted at registration and now you don;t know how this site works. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn what is OK and what isn't, then come back if and when you have a valid issue. You'll find plenty of people willing to help at that stage.

Comment: *I need the onload event code to carry out that functionality.* What makes you assume that, I wonder?

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I don't need your help from scratch am just trying to work along with Windows registry so that I can associate .mp3 files with my Media player so I needed someone to help me out with it, cause my Media player work's just fine